# The use of nearly similar words - Until and unless & each and every

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

This is the first question I had asked [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134802/the-use-of-nearly-similar-words/134803#134803). But things went in other direction and ultimately, I moved to this board as advised.

**The question:**

I have heard this from many. They use **'each and every'** and **'until and unless'** in one sentence. Is this usage correct? How?

See this -

> *I want **each and every one** of you to follow the instruction.* 
>   
>   *I want **every one** of you to follow the instruction.*

Also,

> *First of all, you have to understand what she means.*
>   
> *First, you have to understand what she means.* - “First” is **always** the first among all, right?

This is surprising (but confirmed)

> The word 'revert' does mean *back* in most of the cases still, using **revert back** is correct!

If we could convey the message by putting just ***one* word, why go for redundancy?**

Comment: I don't think *revert back* is surprising, personally.  If you expect natural language not to be redundant, you'll be surprised time and time again.

Comment: This is an interesting question, because so many writing guides exhort beginning writers to [eliminate redundancy](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=eliminate+redundancy&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). Yet phrases such as the ones you mention, as well as _any and all, anyone and everyone, nook and cranny, forever and always_, and _rest and relaxation_ abound. Such phrases are often considered acceptable, though, because they add a lyrical, almost poetic emphasis. I don't think it's a coincidence that so many of these are alliterative.

Comment: RE: _"First" is always the first among all, right?_ That's a bad example of a redundancy, because such a construct might be used for **parallelism**, e.g.: _First, you have to do this... Next, you have to do that..._ and so forth.

Comment: @J.R. The example is **'first of all'**

Comment: Ah! My bad. Yes, that is a bit wordy. A similar one that is sometimes used for emphasis is **first and foremost**.

Comment: Hmmm, not to play dev's advocate, but I don't think "each and every one" is redundant. "Each" feels like it refers to me as an individual while "every one" feels like it refers to me as a member of a group. For example, if someone were to say to me, "I want each of you to drink this Kool-Aid," I could imagine myself saying, "All of us? Every one of us? Including me?" Saying "each and every" would prevent me from finding a loophole because it would indicate to me, "Yes, you, both as an individual, and as a member of this group of Kool-Aid drinkers."

Comment: [Consider this article.](http://www.studyenglishtoday.net/english-grammar-using-each-and-every.html)

Comment: Also consider [this question and answer about the formation of verbs in Mandarin using two verbs already very similar in meaning](http://chinesepod.com/community/conversations/post/13342). I just bring it up to show you that this is not a phenomenon limited to English, so perhaps there is no why, except that this is how the language developed.

Comment: Plus, I think you answer your own question within your question: Why go for redundancy? Because [it's redundant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(linguistics)#Rhetoric).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Each and every* uses the repetition for **emphasis**.  As [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/each_and_every) says:

> Each without exception; *used for emphasis.*
>   　　"*Do not leave without checking **each and every** door to make sure it is locked.*"

*Until and unless* uses the repetition for emphasis as well.  This phrase, however, is somewhat less common, and I think it's used mainly in formal contexts.  (I was unable to find a dictionary that listed *until and unless*.)

To give you an idea of relative frequency, here are the terms I searched for in [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), along with how many results I found for each search term:

```
  each and every       1500
  every and each       2

  until and unless     58
  unless and until     137
```

You'll notice that *each and every* is a fixed phrase which doesn't occur in reverse order, but *until and unless* is actually more common the other way around.  (Thanks to J.R. for pointing this out in a comment!)

Comment: Hmmm, I would say it also clarifies. For example, having someone say, "Every one is unique" or "Each person is unique" feels different for me as the listener. I would feel that the former had just been a generalization while the second would feel more directed towards me as the individual. So while it does emphasize, "each without exception," I would say that it also clarifies, "When I say without exception, I _mean_, without exception."